# Take variable from class in another class

Tags: c#, winforms

Good day,
i read this topic: [Access variable from another method in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216253/access-variable-from-another-method-in-another-class#) but its not helping for me.

My Class (config.cs in Controlcenter.Data) looks like this:

```
public class config
{
    public string conn;
    private MySqlConnection connect;
    public void db_connection()
    {
        conn = "Server=localhost;Database=csharptest;Uid=root;Pwd=";
        connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
        connect.Open();
    }
}
```

In frmLogin.cs (Controlcenter.ConsoleApp) i can take the Metho db_connection:

```
config myclass = new config();
myclass.db_connection();
```

All fine.
So my test connection code in frmLogin.cs is working:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        config myclass = new config();
        myclass.db_connection();
        MessageBox.Show("Erfolg");
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

But now I want to do a loginscript whos not working cuz frmLogin.cs cant find "conn" and "connect" from config.cs

```
private bool validate_login(string user, string pass)
{
    connect_db();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users where username=@user and password=@pass";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
    cmd.Connection = connect;
    MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (login.Read())
    {
        connect.Close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        connect.Close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I take the variables from config.cs into frmLogin.cs ?

Comment: Declare your config as private outside of your `button1_click` `private config myclass = new config();`. Now you can access your `myclass` within your formLogin.cs

Comment: its not working. I declared private config myclass = new config(); in the top of my frmLogin.cs but frmLogin.cs still cant find "connect" from config.cs

Comment: you have to declare your `connect` as `public`

Comment: i declared conn and MySqlConnection connect to public in config.cs yes. But it still cant found it in frmLogin.cs

Comment: okay its fixed. I forgot to change connect in frmLogin.cs to myclass.connect.