# use of an unassigned variable 'format', "attr1", "attr2", "attr3"

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can we pass the values from the return of other method?
I wanted to get the values of `format`, `attr1`, `attr2`, `attr3` from the `GetFormat()` method. But somehow I am unable to get it. What is it that I am missing?
However I did initialize them, but it didn't work.

```
public static bool GetFormat()
{
    string format, attr1, attr2, attr3 = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string globalFormat = GetGlobalConfigStringValue(GLOBAL_CONFIG_ADVANCED_FULL_NAME);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(globalFormat.ToString());
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//DisplayName");
        format = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Format").InnerText.ToString();
        attr1 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute1").InnerText.ToString();
        attr2 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute2").InnerText.ToString();
        attr3 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute3").InnerText.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(globalFormat) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attr1) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attr2))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
 
public static string GetProfileDisplayName(string profileUID)
{
    string format, attr1, attr2, attr3 = string.Empty;
    if (GetFormat())
    {
        using (var context = GetAccessEntitiesContext())
        {
            var user = context.vw_Profile.Where(x => x.ProfileUID.Equals(profileUID)).FirstOrDefault();

            return string.Format(format, user.GetType().GetProperty(attr1).GetValue(user), user.GetType().GetProperty(attr2).GetValue(user), user.GetType().GetProperty(attr3).GetValue(user));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        format = "{0} {1}";
        attr1 = "FirstName";
        attr2 = "LastName";
        using (var context = GetAccessEntitiesContext())
        {
            var user = context.vw_Profile.Where(x => x.ProfileUID.Equals(profileUID)).FirstOrDefault();

            return string.Format(format, user.GetType().GetProperty(attr1).GetValue(user), user.GetType().GetProperty(attr2).GetValue(user));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Tuple` or `out` parameters or a class type to return required parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# referencing a variable from another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9301197/c-sharp-referencing-a-variable-from-another-method)

Comment: You have now defined them as local variables (which get destroyed after the method finishes). Each method has its own set. That they use the same names is unimportant.

Comment: @HereticMonkey no i cant seem to understand How to implement it in my case. If possible can u help?

Comment: There are a number of questions about this subject; search for "c# use variables defined in another function" in your favorite search engine. Maybe [Access variable from another method in another class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22216253/215552) or [Calling a Variable from another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1392017/215552)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to acheive this, you have to refactor your `GetFormat` method.

**Way 1) Make a [`DTO`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and return that [`DTO`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) from your method -**

```
public static GetFormatModel GetFormat()
{
    GetFormatModel model = new GetFormatModel();
    try
    {
        string globalFormat = GetGlobalConfigStringValue(GLOBAL_CONFIG_ADVANCED_FULL_NAME);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(globalFormat.ToString());
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//DisplayName");
        model.format = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Format").InnerText.ToString();
        model.attr1 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute1").InnerText.ToString();
        model.attr2 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute2").InnerText.ToString();
        model.attr3 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute3").InnerText.ToString();
        
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(globalFormat)
        || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.attr1) 
        || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.attr2))
        {
            model.isSuccess = false;
            return model;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        model.isSuccess = false;
        return model;
    }

    model.isSuccess = true;
    return model;
}

// DTO
public class GetFormatModel
{
    public bool isSuccess { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string attr1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string attr2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string attr3 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

**Way 2) Return a [`generic Tuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2?view=netcore-3.1)**

```
public static Tuple<bool, string, string, string, string> GetFormat()
{
    Tuple<bool, string, string, string, string> tplGetFormat = default(Tuple<bool, string, string, string, string>);
    try
    {
        string globalFormat = GetGlobalConfigStringValue(GLOBAL_CONFIG_ADVANCED_FULL_NAME);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(globalFormat.ToString());
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//DisplayName");
        tplGetFormat.Item2 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Format").InnerText.ToString();
        tplGetFormat.Item3 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute1").InnerText.ToString();
        tplGetFormat.Item4 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute2").InnerText.ToString();
        tplGetFormat.Item5 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute3").InnerText.ToString();
        
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(globalFormat)
        || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tplGetFormat.Item3) 
        || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tplGetFormat.Item4))
        {
            tplGetFormat.Item1 = false;
            return tplGetFormat;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        tplGetFormat.Item1 = false;
        return tplGetFormat;
    }

    tplGetFormat.Item1 = true;
    return tplGetFormat;
}
```

**Way 3) Return [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) parameters -**

```
public static bool GetFormat(
out string format, 
out string attr1, 
out string attr2, 
out string attr3
)
{
    format = attr1 = attr2 = attr3 = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string globalFormat = GetGlobalConfigStringValue(GLOBAL_CONFIG_ADVANCED_FULL_NAME);

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(globalFormat.ToString());
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//DisplayName");
        format = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Format").InnerText.ToString();
        attr1 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute1").InnerText.ToString();
        attr2 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute2").InnerText.ToString();
        attr3 = nodes[0].SelectSingleNode("Atrribute3").InnerText.ToString();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(globalFormat) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attr1) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attr2))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// Usage
string format = attr1 = attr2 = attr3 = string.Empty;
GetFormat(out format, out attr1, out attr2, out attr3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to 'return' multiple values from a method in `C#`, there's few ways to do it. One of the simplest is to use multiple `out` parameters. That is, the parameters of the method are declared with the keyword `out`, and you call the method by passing parameters from outside with the same keyword. Then, inside the method when you assign a value to it, that value can be referenced from outside.

```
public static void GetValues(out int a, out int b, out int c)
{
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;
}
```

Call it like:

```
GetValues(out int valA, out int valB, out int valC);
```

And print:

```
Console.WriteLine("a: {0}", valA);
Console.WriteLine("b: {0}", valB);
Console.WriteLine("c: {0}", valC);
```

**Output:**

```
a: 1
b: 2
c: 3
```

Another idea is to define a class that will contain all the values you want to return as properties, and inside the method create an object of it and return it as a normal return value.

```
public class GetValueClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
}

public static GetValueClass GetValues()
{
    var values = new GetValueClass() { A = 11, B = 22, C = 33 };
    return values;
}
```

Call and print values:

```
GetValueClass values = GetValues();
Console.WriteLine("A: {0}", values.A);
Console.WriteLine("B: {0}", values.B);
Console.WriteLine("C: {0}", values.C);
```

**Output:**

```
A: 11
B: 22
C: 33
```

### NOTE

In this line of code:

```
string format, attr1, attr2, attr3 = string.Empty;
```

I think what you expects it to do is assign `string.Empty` to all 4 `string` variables. But unlike some other programming languages `C#` doesn't do it that way; it only assigns `string.Empty` to `attr3`, and the others will be `null`.